# iPhone Safari link to maps.google.com without launching the default Map App

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mobile-safari

I have a iPhone web app that has html links to http://maps.google.com. iPhone by default will launch the default Map app when user tapped the links.

I wonder if there is a way to tell iPhone open the https://maps.google.com website instead of fire up the default Map app?

NOTE: My app is a HTML5 web app hosted on a server and not a native app

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers for your questions

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)mainWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    //Allows for twitter links
    [self.mainWebView loadRequest:request];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

Try this code it will open the links in the same webview

Comment: Hi Rishabh, sorry i did not make it clear, mine is a HTML web app (not native). However thanks for replying. Updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: added another answer that will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

oh its not a native App not a problem.
there is a feature in phonegap which can be used nicely to redirect the links to a small child browser.
the plugin is called ChildBrowser

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser

this is a very nice tool which can be used to redirect all links to a mini-browser rather than any application.

Check it out works smooth

Comment: Nice, thanks.  But i think ChildBrowser only works with PhoneGap. My project is a web app based on Sencha Touch

Comment: Sencha touch works hand in hand with phonegap , its mentioned on Sencha Touch's homepage..